# Building a recursive function in Matlab to draw adaptive trapezoidal quadrature

Tags: matlab, recursion, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I want to build a function that takes in the tolerance level, upper and lower bounds, and the function, to calculate the Adaptive Trapezoidal Quadrature, as well as drawing a figure, such as this one:[image]

Because I need the node values to draw my figure, I tried coding as follows:

```
function [node, approx] = aq(f,a,b,tol)
t = (b-a)*(f(b)+f(a))/2;
    if abs((t2 - t)/3) > tol %Since T(2)-T(1)=E(1)-E(2)=3*E(2)
        m = (a+b)/2;
        [node1, approx1] = aq(f,a,m,tol/2);
        [node2, approx2] = aq(f,m,b,tol/2);
        node = [node1(1:end-1) node2];
        approx = approx1+approx2;
    else
        node = [a,b];
        approx = tf;
    end
end
```

I have two problems with my code: One is that, obviously, t2 is not defined. I do not know how to define it because, depending on whether the quadrature rule, the next estimation could include both sides of the trapezoid or just one. I'm confused. Maybe I need to define a separate function that calculates trapezoidal area.

The second problem is that even if I put in a function with its known integral value (for example,

> tol = 10^-2;
>
> f = @(x) exp(x)*sin(x);
>
> a=0; b=pi;
>
> .5*(exp(pi)+1) %is our exact integral value, we can put this into the if statement

But the code goes into infinite loop. I don't know how to stop this, because theoretically, it's supposed to converge.

Please go easy on me as I am a math major in a numerical analysis class, and this is my first year coding. Thanks!

**Edit: Thanks! Got it to work :)**
[image]

Comment: Counterintuitively, trapezoidal quadrature is worse than midpoint quadrature. I'd always use the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By context, `t2` is the composite trapezoidal formula for two segments,

```
t2 = (b-a)/2*(f(a)+2*f(m)+f(b))/2
```

The error is then the second iterated difference, with some factor in front,

```
(t2-t)/3 = (b-a)/4*(-f(a)+2*f(m)-f(b))
```

and the Richardson extrapolation of the trapezoidal values is the Simpson value

```
tf = (4*t2-t)/3 = (b-a)/6*(f(a)+4*f(m)+f(b))
```

You should introduce some data structure or other mechanism to remove the multiple evaluation of `f` at the same points. It is not overly critical, but might remove a non-trivial factor from the computation time.